# Perché in Turandot la Cina è chiamata China?

Tags: word-choice, pronunciation

Ascoltando l'opera *Turandot*, con musica di Giacomo Puccini e Franco Alfano, e libretto di Giuseppe Adami e Renato Simoni, un fatto che ha sempre attirato la mia attenzione è che il paese dove si svolge l'azione, con capoluogo a Pechino, viene chiamato China (pronunciato /'kina/) invece di Cina. Il libretto si può trovare su molti siti web. Per esempio, ecco il [documento del Teatro Verdi di Salerno](https://www.google.com/url?q=http://www.teatroverdisalerno.it/shared/binary/538_1_0/libretto%2520turandot.pdf&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwiMitKJytDlAhWhAWMBHbnTCFUQFjABegQIBxAB&usg=AOvVaw333qbTxuE0xQLVyNMphcAh). Potete cercarci "China" e vedrete che appare parecchie volte nel testo.

Qualcuno di voi mi saprebbe spiegare qualcosa sulla ragione di questa curiosa scelta? Ho ricercato con Google, ma non ho trovato nessuna informazione al riguardo.

Comment: Buona domanda... Credo che c'entri questo: http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/china3 (ma non è una risposta perché lì si parla solo dell'inchiostro).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ho trovato in questo post sul forum [OperaClick](http://www.operaclick.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=16458) una domanda simile alla tua:

> **Turandot: China (/ˈki.na/) oppure Cina (/ˈʧi.na/)?**
>
> Gentili esperti, un
>   quesito a cui non ho potuto dare risposta, spigolando in rete. Sullo
>   spartito è scritto "China"; qualcuno canta China altri Cina. Hoepli
>   dice: Cina, China.
>   * Perché si dice Olimpiadi in Cina, viaggio in Cina, commercio con la Cina, ma inchiostro di China? E perché blu Cina e nero di China? Non
>   stiamo forse parlando dello stesso paese? Certamente. Addirittura,
>   fino ai primi del Novecento, Cina e China si alternavano nell’uso, e
>   così pure si diceva indifferentemente chinese e cinese.
>   * Tutto questo si spiega con un errore di lettura: un’errata lettura del nome portoghese China, con cui cominciammo a conoscere molti
>   secoli fa questo paese, allora molto lontano. Ma i portoghesi, allora
>   colonizzatori, leggono il ch come noi leggiamo la c, cioè palatale,
>   quasi Scina, riproducendo così la pronuncia cinese. Noi, invece,
>   leggemmo la grafia portoghese all’italiana.
>   * Ciò premesso, è chiaro che oggi chiamare Cina il paese, e dire invece inchiostro di China è un’assurdità, ma ce la dobbiamo tenere
>   così com’è: la denominazione inchiostro di China resiste indisturbata
>   perché è diventata un nome tecnico. E così pure nero di China. Mentre
>   blu Cina, denominazione recente, è sfuggita all’equivoco.
>
> Puccini, Adami e Simoni cosa hanno detto?

A cui viene risposto:

> Una pronuncia filologica del libretto impone ovviamente la dizione
>   /ˈkina/, cosí come —so già che tutti voi sapete, ma repetita iuvant—
>   «Turandot» va pronunciato a rigore /-ˈdɔt/, e non /-ˈdo/ alla
>   francese, né tantomeno /-ˈdɔ/ (che sarebbe l’adattamento
>   dell’adattamento francese; cfr fr. «bordeaux» /boʁdo/ > it. «bordò»
>   /-ˈdɔ/).
>
> **«China», che si sostituisce al «Catai» del Milione, nasce —come lei
>   riporta giustamente— dalla lettura all’italiana del portoghese «China»
>   /ʃi'nɐ/, cioè appunto /ˈkina/, che s’alterna per qualche tempo con la
>   variante «piú rigorosa» (per cosí dire) Cina /ˈʧina/. Non sarebbe il
>   primo caso di errore di lettura, nella storia della lingua italiana,
>   che produce vocaboli nuovi o li filtra al loro primo ingresso
>   nell’idioma: si vedano ad esempio collimare (err. per collineare),
>   zenit (alterazione trascrittiva dell’arabo samt) e ovest (err. per il
>   francese ouest). Una volta imposte nell’uso, tali forme restano
>   canoniche e non sono da aborrire.**
>
> Tuttavia, nel caso di varianti in competizione, non è raro che una di
>   esse —in genere quella caduta definitivamente in disuso—, legatasi in
>   polirematiche stabili, sopravviva alla propria desuetudine. **Sicché, in
>   realtà, non c’è niente di «assurdo» se chiamiamo il Paese «Cina» ma
>   diciamo/scriviamo «inchiostro di China» (o «di china»; sempre
>   minuscolo quando lessicalizzato nel solo «china», sostantivo
>   femminile).** Esempi analoghi? «Lana d’Angora» o «d’ angora» /ˈangora/
>   (o semplicemente «angora», s.f.) per «d’Ankara», o ancora —scavando
>   piú a fondo— «cravatta» e «casacca» per «croata» e «kazaca».
>
> È indubbio, per concludere, che il compositore e i librettisti
>   pronunciassero /ˈkina/, com’era allora canonico, e che a tale dizione
>   i cantanti debbano scrupolosamente aderire. (Controversa invece la
>   questione di «Turandot», poiché, stando alla Raisa, Puccini quella t
>   non l’avrebbe pronunciata. Diversamente, suppongo io, dai letterati
>   Adami e Simoni.)

Sul [*Grande Dizionario della Lingua Italiana*](http://www.gdli.it/pdf_viewer/Scripts/pdf.js/web/viewer.asp?file=/PDF/GDLI03/GDLI_03_ocr_85.pdf), vol. 3 (CERT-DAG) pag. 79, si può leggere:

> Dal nome della Cina, secondo la grafia *China* dei primi esploratori portoghesi,
>   che ne furono informati dagl'Indiani o dai Malesi. Il nome della China
>   è derivato dalla dinastia cinese *Ch'in* (255-206 a.C.), che allora
>   unificò il paese in un grande impero. Fino a poco tempo fa s'è scritto
>     ‘China’  e  ‘Chinese’. Cfr. *Boccardo*, I-519: «Quella numerosa
>   popolazione che... fu il primo movente dei progressi industriali ed
>   economici della China, è eziandio la causa di grandi miserie», e «Il
>   Chinese trascura e disprezza (opposto in ciò all'Indiano) come inutili
>   i fatti che non hanno se non un valore teorico e speculativo»  (ma
>   nell'esponente scrive *Cina*).

Comment: Quindi, se ho capito bene, all'inizio del Novecento questa era una delle pronunce standard del nome di quel paese (in alternanza con /'ʧina/)?

Comment: Ho aggiornato la risposta con un estratto dal GDLI.

Comment: Grazie mille, @abarisone! In effetto, a volte la "ricerca libera" non funziona bene. Io ho usato la "ricerca in sequenza".

Comment: L'opera di Girolamo Boccardo citata nel [*GDLI*](http://www.gdli.it/JPG/GDLI_indice_autori/00048.jpg)  è, in effetti, della seconda metà dell'Ottocento.